# What is the Server ID and CLSID of Simatic NET OPC Server to program in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, observer-pattern, opc

I am using Simatic NET OPC Server..

Please help me , how to get Server ID and CLSID of Simatic NET OPC

Comment: http://support.automation.siemens.com/OST/llisapi.dll?func=cslib.csinfo&objId=26425944&nodeid0=16502685&load=treecontent&lang=en&siteid=cseus&aktprim=0&objaction=csview&extranet=standard&viewreg=OST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OPC Server : Simatic NET

Server ID : opcda://localhost/OPC.SimaticNET.1/{B6EACB30-42D5-11D0-9517-0020AFAA4B3C}

CLSID :{B6EACB30-42D5-11D0-9517-0020AFAA4B3C}

Tags :

SERVER:\DiagnosticsSummary\CumulatedSubscriptionCount

SERVER:\Capabilities\MinSupportedUpdateRate

Comment: @user3331091...Yes..Definitely

Comment: If I am specifically using a DP coupler with Siemens, would I do opcda://localhost/OPC.SimaticNET.DP.1/{ListOfRegNumbers} for the server ID instead of just SimaticNET.1?